# bloquear y habilitar etiqueta <a></a> en html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buenos días tengo un header con inicio, carne, carne esta hecho con una etiqueta  ya logre bloquear esta etiqueta con jquery de la siguiente manera.

```
$(".carnet").bind("click", false);
```

necesito que cuando se envie el formulario que esta en aviso importante quede habilitada esta etiqueta carne, lo intente habilitarlo con jquery de la siguiente forma.

```
    $("#formAutoD").submit(function () {
  $(".carnet").unbind("click", false);
});
```

pero solo queda habilitado una vez y yo necesito que esta quede habilitada durante el día, hasta que envíen el formulario y al otro día vuelva y se bloquee.

este es mi formulario el que esta en la pestaña aviso importante.

```
<form role="form" id="formAutoD"> <?php $nump = 1;

                                                $array_p1 = array_shift($array_preguntas);
                                                ?>
                <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-1">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Chequeo</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $array_p1[0]; ?></h4>

                            <?php echo $array_p1[1]; ?>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right " type="button">Siguiente</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-primary setup-content" id="step-2">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Chequeo
                    </div>
                    <?php $nump = 1;
                    foreach ($array_preguntas as $idPregunta => $inputPregunta) {
                    ?>
                        <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 2px !important;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">* <?php echo $inputPregunta[0]; ?></h4>
                                <?php echo $inputPregunta[1]; ?>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $nump++;
                            if ($numPreguntas == $nump) {
                            ?>
                                <button class="btn nextBtn btn-success btnregistrardiagnostico" type="submit" onclick="bloquear()">Registrar !</button>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    <?
                    } // End for
                    ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="IDDiagnostico" id="IDDiagnostico" value="<?php echo $IDDiagnostico; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="action">
            </form>
```

[[image: header1]

Este es el código del nav.

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <?php
                $_GET["m"] = empty($_GET["m"]) ? "" : $_GET["m"];

                if ((!empty($datosSesion->IDSocio) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/index.php") || $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/login.php") { ?>
                    <li><a href="index.php"></a></li>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li class="<?php if ($_GET["m"] == "") echo "active"; ?>"><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>

                    <?php

                    foreach ($datosSesion->MODULOS_MENU as $classModulos) {
                    ?>
                        <li class="<?php if ($_GET["m"] == $classModulos["m"]) echo "active"; ?>">
                            <a href="<?php echo $classModulos["URL"] . "?m=" . $classModulos["m"]; ?>" <?php if ($classModulos["URL"] == "perfil.php") {

                                                                                                        ?> class="carnet" <?php } ?>>
                                <?php echo $classModulos["NombreModulo"]; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } // End foreach
                    ?>


                <?php } // End if
                ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones de jQuery bind() y unbind() quedaron obsoletas en la versión 1.7 de jQuery. Estas funciones asignan y eliminan eventos en los elementos del DOM.

Te dejo enlace a un post donde te explican como sustituirlas por las funciones on() y off() que son las validas a partir de la 1.7.

Artículo: [jQuery bind() y unbidn(): Funciones obsoletas a sustituir por on() y off()](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-bind-4727/)

Comment: pero igual con estas dos funciones solo me queda habilitado una vez y después vuelve y se bloquea.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo completo de tu jQuery.

Comment: `$(".carnet").on("click", false);
$("#formAutoD").submit(function () {
    $(".carnet").off("click", false);
  });`

Comment: Y el código que forma tu menú de cabecera también, por favor, gracias.

Comment: te lo coloque en la pregunta

Comment: Prueba con esto: $( "#formAutoD" ).submit(function( event ) {
                  $(".carnet").off("click", false); 
                  event.preventDefault();
                });

Comment: no tampoco cuando ya le doy click a inicio y vuelvo a carne ya aparece bloqueado

Comment: Probablemente cuando vuelvas a inicio aparezca bloqueado porque vuelve a cargar el $(".carnet").on("click", false);